# Unable to detect Beacon when Device already in Beacon range & then we turn on Bluetooth & application is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon, clbeaconregion

I have implemented Beacon with local notification.
Every thing works fine for the case when bluetooth in ON & then device enters the beacon range & app is in "Not running" state.
But, when device is already in Beacon range & then Bluetooth is turned ON, no delegate gets called. Is it a limitation or am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you expect a call backnin this case?  The region state has not changed.

Comment: Then how would i show Notification for that beacon when user turned on bluetooth in beacon range?

Comment: For your scenario where the device is "already in Beacon range & then the Bluetooth is turned ON, no delegate is called" - is this while the app is in a Terminated (force quit) state?

Comment: need code...in which method application is killed?

Comment: "But, when device is already in Beacon range & then Bluetooth is turned ON, no delegate gets called" do you change you device location at this situation?

Comment: @MarioKurt : Yes app is in  a Terminated (force quit) state

Comment: @SMi: I didn't change the location at this situation.

Comment: Give some code. Which methods you implement from CLLocationManagerDelegate? What is your CLBeaconMajorValue and minor value last time it works?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the Core Location framework.

When an application is terminated "Not Running" state, it can be re-launched due to location manager region didEnter / didExit region events. Your location manager will not receive region enter / exit events if you toggle your Bluetooth on and off while the application is terminated. The only way you'll be able to get didEnter / didExit events to fire is by physically entering or exiting one of your beacon regions by crossing their detection threshold.

- Terminated apps will wake up on region didEnter / didExit events.

> The region monitoring service delivers events normally while an app is running in the foreground or background. (You can use this service for both geographic and beacon regions.) For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events.

- Beacon ranging will not wake up your app.

> (If the beacon region’s notifyEntryStateOnDisplay property is true, waking the device causes the app to range for beacons for a few seconds in the background.) This service does not relaunch iOS apps that have been terminated; however, you can be relaunched by monitoring beacon regions using the region monitoring service.